# What circumstances make Heighten Turning worthwhile?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, undead, statistics

The feat **Heighten Turning** has the following as part of its benefit:

> When you turn or rebuke undead, you may choose a number no higher than your cleric level. Add that number to your turning check, while subtracting it from your turning damage roll. (*Libris Mortis* 27)

So we're all on the same page, here's a summary of the special attack [turn undead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#turnOrRebukeUndead):

- When a cleric makes a turn undead attempt, the cleric first determines the maximum Hit Dice of the largest single undead that can be affected by making a **turning check** (1d20 + Charisma modifier), the result found on a chart that yields a Hit Dice outcome of between the cleric's level −4 and the cleric's level +4.
- Then the cleric determines how many total Hit Dice of undead are *actually* affected by making a **turning damage roll** (2d6 + cleric level + Charisma modifier). There is no upper limit to this result.

The feat Heighten Turning lets the cleric increase the turning *check* by +1 but decrease the turning *damage roll* by −1. The cleric can do this to a value up to the cleric's level. Reversing the polarity would've made the feat's use obvious in the face of a horde of low-powered undead creatures, but the way it's written instead makes the feat just weird: The cleric tries to turn a lone powerful undead creature while simultaneously limiting the size of the creature *and* his ability to affect it.

**What are the optimal circumstances in which to use the feat Heighten Turning?** That is, what numbers have to be present on both the cleric's side and the enemies' side for the feat Heighten Turning to be a good idea? Is the feat one that looked good on paper but is useless in actual play? Is there ever a certain point at which, or a certain build wherein, it's the ideal feat?

Comment: I've included the tag `statistics` because I think this might ultimately be a gaming math question (with *a lot* of variables). However, answers avoiding statistics are fine.

Comment: I just noted that there is somehow no mention in the feat description of *when* you decide to use it or how much to add. It could thus be useful in ensuring that you reach high enough. Otherwise it might also be useful for a cleric with low charisma targeting a single undead.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't think that rules quirk does the cleric much good as, because turning takes place in steps, the bonus is always applied *before* the penalty. So the cleric could, I guess, impose a penalty on his turning damage roll *without* gaining the bonus on the turning check, but I don't know of a situation in which that's useful. Of course, I don't know of a situation in which *the feat* is useful, so there's that. (An interesting idea, though.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan It *is* useful to purposefully ruin your turning damage in some situations, e.g. to precisely turn all the enemy zombies near _you_ but not the allied zombies near the enemy.  Such situations, where excess damage is _bad_, are very rare, however.

Comment: Enter the Radiant Servant of Undead Slaying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the optimal circumstances in which to use the feat Heighten
>   Turning?

The optimal circumstances would be obviously a situation, where you reap only the benefits. But is this possible? It is.

The turning check as D20 has a 15% probability to end up with a value of three or less, the damage roll is guaranteed to be 3 though, assuming you are always at least level 1.

**Level 2 Cleric versus 4 enemies with 1 hit die**

A level 2 cleric is guaranteed to turn 4 hit dice, but has a chance of 30% to fail completely, by rolling 1-6 on the D20. This chance to fail is constant.

Chance to fail completely: 30%
Chance to turn all enemies: 70%
(100% - 30% chance to fail completely)

The group has a 30% chance to end up with 4 enemies. The group either ends up with no enemies or all of them.

Let's now use the feature to add the +1/-1 modifier to the rolls:

Chance to fail completely: 25%
Chance to turn all enemies: 73%

Okay, we improved the maximum hit dice odds by the 5%, we only need to not roll 1-5 now. But how can we get a better result by adding a negative modifier? Well, you don't, you still decrease your odds, but in sum and comparison to before, it doesn't matter.

There is a chance of 1/36 to roll 1 + 1 as damage roll, which is 3% rounded up. Only this way you end up with less than 4 total hit dice. So, there is a 97% chance to roll any other combination that saves your day. There is also a 75% chance to not fail the maximum hit dice check. The probability of not failing both checks (97% * 75%) is 73%.

Whenever the enemies total hit dice are near your guaranteed damage roll, you can reap most benefits.

Otherwise, the feature gives you options. 4 enemies together are stronger than the 4 individuals. It's usually more beneficial for the group to have a guaranteed reduction of enemies instead of sometimes many and sometimes few enemies.

**Level 2 Cleric versus 1 enemy with 6 hit dice**

This is a simple one. Your probability to make the maximum hit dice check is zero. Which is a really bad probability. But you only need to roll a 4 or more on 2d6 for the damage roll, which is quite a good chance - 91%! But it's a waste. What's the point of a nearly guaranteed damage roll if there is a guaranteed turning check failure?

A +2/-2 modifier will give you at least a chance of 5% to make the maximum hit dice check. And the chance to at least roll 6 as damage roll is 72%, which isn't that bad. Your overall chance (5% * 72%) is still crappy 3%. But 3% is more than 0%.

Comment: Interesting. So, in a sense, like the similar feat Power Attack, the feat's best used when you already know you're going to win *or* when you've no chance of winning without it.

Answer (score 0):

**Speaking simply, on the high end or the low end.**

When you desperately want to turn something with more HD than you have cleric levels, (aka turning a single high-CR undead), you might not need that much 'turning damage' aka 'amount of hd turned' but want a higher chance to actually affect it at all.  The only real way to calculate this is through metagaming, or a GM who treats knowledge checks as 'you know the monster's stats'.

On the low end, when you just don't want to roll like, a 2, and not be able to turn the low-HD ghouls despite being a higher cleric level than they have HD, you can just take away a few 'turning damage' points to push that from 'needing to roll a 4 or better' to 'needing to roll a 1'.  Aka, making the initial turning check a shoe-in.

**Is the feat any good?**

Nope.  Get the ones which give +effective turning levels.  Get the one that activates the relic item that does the same.  Counting as a higher level cleric makes the turning check relatively pointless, with the amount of etls you can get for the cost of a feat.  And if you're caring about turning, be a Sun Cleric and just straight up burn undead into actual cinders with Greater Turning.

**Is there a certain build where it's good**

Sorta.  The maxed out charisma turning cleric build.  Where you already have all the stuff to make your turning as murderous as possible, in an undead-heavy campaign.  The high charisma means you can spend points of 'turning damage' without making it useless, so the 'high end' undead can be affected by your 1d20+charisma+heighten turning bonus'd check.  Since 2d6 is unlikely to roll less than four, you're effectively going to be making the turning check 1d20+charismax2, with when you're really going for it, 1d20+charismax2+3 (average roll on 2d6 being 7), and with a charisma of 5 and average of 10.5, pushing the turning check into 'very unlikely to get below level+3' territory.